# How to SQL Group by Date Hour

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

Hi I have a below table.

```
ID  Created Date                Deposit Money

18  2021-01-14 17:19:10.932030  16862895
17  2021-01-14 13:18:13.944762  625000
16  2021-01-14 12:19:55.565888  616000
15  2021-01-14 11:19:10.932030  16862895
14  2021-01-14 10:18:13.944762  625000
13  2021-01-14 09:19:55.565888  616000
12  2021-01-14 09:01:10.932030  16862895
11  2021-01-14 08:02:13.944000  625000
10  2021-01-14 08:01:55.565888  616000
9   2021-01-14 07:19:10.932030  16862895
8   2021-01-14 07:19:10.932030  16862895
7   2021-01-14 07:18:13.944762  625000
6   2021-01-14 07:18:13.944762  625000
5   2021-01-14 06:19:55.565888  616000
4   2021-01-14 06:19:55.565888  616000
3   2021-01-13 21:32:46.538236  19245
2   2021-01-13 19:33:30.693695  25560
1   2021-01-13 18:13:30.693695  588820
```

I want resut.

```
2021-01-13 16:00 ~ 2021-01-14 09:59  sum(deposit_money)
2021-01-14 10:00 ~ 2021-01-14 12:59  sum(deposit_money)
2021-01-14 13:00 ~ 2021-01-14 15:59  sum(deposit_money)
2021-01-14 16:00 ~ 2021-01-15 09:59  sum(deposit_money)
```

.....

```
yesterday 16:00 ~ today 10:00
today 10:00 ~ today 13:00
today 13:00 ~ today 16:00
today 16:00 ~ tommorrow 10:00
```

I don't know how to set up Group by.
Thank you if you can reply on your own

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), 
take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). 
Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, 
post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt

Answer (score 1):

You could build a subquery with a schedule for the desired hours, like in this example:

```sql
SELECT p.start_from, p.end_to, SUM(t.deposit) AS total 
FROM deposits t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 16, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS start_from,
        TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 10 * 60 * 60 - 1, CURDATE()) AS end_to
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 10, CURDATE()),
        TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 13 * 60 * 60 - 1, CURDATE())
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 13, CURDATE()),
        TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 16 * 60 * 60 - 1, CURDATE())
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 16, CURDATE()),
        TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 10 * 60 * 60 - 1, DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))

) p ON created BETWEEN start_from AND end_to
GROUP BY p.start_from, p.end_to
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j53r9UAcPNDVfcW1AVdbeM/1)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you really want this for all dates, not just the current date.

You can assign the beginning of the period using a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when time(created_date) < '10:00:00'
             then (date(created_date) - interval 1 day) + interval 16 hour
             when  time(created_date) < '13:00:00'
             then date(created_date) + interval 10 hour
             when time(created_date) < '16:00:00'
             then date(created_date) + interval 13 hour
             else date(created_date) + interval 16 hour
        end)
from t;
```

You can then easily incorporate this into an aggregation:

```
select (case when time(created_date) < '10:00:00'
             then (date(created_date) - interval 1 day) + interval 16 hour
             when  time(created_date) < '13:00:00'
             then date(created_date) + interval 10 hour
             when time(created_date) < '16:00:00'
             then date(created_date) + interval 13 hour
             else date(created_date) + interval 16 hour
        end) as period,
       count(*)
from t
group by period
order by min(created_date);
```

Note:  This only handles the period start.  That seems sufficient for the results you want.

If you want this only for a period of time, you can include a `where` clause filtering the rows for the time period you want.